# Use Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB for Small Business Workstation?

Tags: windows-10

I'm thinking of buying an Enterprise Edition of Windows 10 for a small business customer. He needs one of his workstations to be very stable (rock solid). An interruption caused by an update is not an option. I thought of Windows 10 Enterprise because of the LTSB (Long Term Service Branch). It seems we can buy a legit license some reputable sellers on the internet.

- If we buy a legit license of Windows 10 Enterprise, will we be able to get like at least 5 years (for example) of patches and security updates?
- If we ever need to upgrade to Current Branch (CB), can we do this without having to purchase SA (Software Assurance)? Or maybe we'd just have to buy a new Windows 10 Enterprise license at that time?
- So LTSB installs only patches, hotfix and security updates right? Can we use Windows update to upgrade the newest CB?

Comment: the LTSB version gets updates for 10 years. So the version from July 2015 is supported till 2025: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=PN&alpha=Windows%2010&Filter=FilterNO

Comment: So if I install current LTSB, it will only install patches and security fixes for the next 10 years? No major upgrades? Correct?

Comment: this is correct. The LTSB gets only security fixes and no new large updates like the version 1511

Comment: Thanks Andre. And, for example, if in 2 years we decide to install the current build of LTSB, will we have to buy a new license?

Comment: I have no idea. But I doubt this.

Comment: OK thanks-a-lot Andre. I appreciate it. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

According to this : 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/uktechnet/archive/2015/07/13/windows-10-licensing-logic.aspx

Look at the table named "Long Term Service Branch is only Available for Windows Enterprise edition" : 
Look at rows "Windows 10 v2015 Enterprise Upgrade" and "Windows 10 Enterprise Upgrade with SA²"

Look at the bottom of the table, in very small text : 
"²If SA dropped, will have perpetual rights to the current LTSBs only, with Downgrade Rights"

I think that explains a lot.

And here's a quote of that website that explains exactly all the questions I had! (Wow! Should've done better Google'Fu before I asked here)

> Windows Enterprise edition is available with or without software
>   assurance. Windows Enterprise without SA allows the customer to deploy
>   a point-in-time LTSB release, or previous ones (downgrade rights in
>   other words) and for that release to still be supported for 5 years.
>   Windows Enterprise edition with SA also gives customers the rights to
>   new LTSB release when they become available (every 2-3 years). They
>   can choose whether to install new releases or not. SA also means the
>   customer gains extended support so their chosen release will be
>   supported for 10 years.
>
> Even if a customer does have LTSB requirements, it’s unlikely that all
>   of their devices will require it so customers with Windows Enterprise
>   with SA (or indeed Windows Education with SA) will be able to mix
>   Current Branch, CBB and LTSB according to their needs.
>
> One important point to note is that Enterprise edition without SA will
>   not enjoy updates on Current Branch either. Customers with Home and
>   Pro editions will always get the latest features for the life of the
>   device. Enterprise edition without SA will not. The release that's
>   installed will eventually become out of date and the customer will
>   need to buy a licence again to update.
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise Edition with SA is available through all
>   Microsoft Volume Licensing Programs (Open, Open Value, Select+, MPSA,
>   EA, etc.). You can visit this blog post to read about how to upgrade
>   to Windows 10.